# .htaccess redirect according to PHP parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to build some redirections with my .htaccess file to deal with some old forum url. I want the redirections to be made according to the PHP parameters (the topic ID).

For instance, something like

```
RewriteEngine On
RedirectPermanent /forum/viewtopic.php?t=123 /page1.html
RedirectPermanent /forum/viewtopic.php?t=345 /page7.html
RedirectPermanent /forum/viewtopic.php?t=89 /page3.html
```

The old and new URL are not related to each other (no PHP parameter has to be kept or something). I want to decide manually in my .htaccess file what to do for each topic ID.

But I can't manage to do that so easily. I tried many things, but nothing works.

Is this possible ? Any idea ?

Thanks a lot !

Edit : additional question : I want to add a global redirection of all the folder /forum to the root of the site ("/"). I guess I can place it after the others, so if no other rule is trigered, this one will be trigered.

I'm trying some things like

```
RewriteRule ^forum /? [L,R=301]
```

But everything I have tried so far redirects me to the "page1.html" (my first rule). Any idea why ? Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

You can't match against the query string using mod_alias's `Redirect`, `RedirectMatch`, etc. You need to use mod_rewrite and match against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^t=123$
RewriteRule ^forum/viewtopic\.php$ /page1.html? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^t=345$
RewriteRule ^forum/viewtopic\.php$ /page7.html? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^t=89$
RewriteRule ^forum/viewtopic\.php$ /page3.html? [L,R=301]
```

NOte that `RewriteEngine` is a mod_rewrite directive, not mod_alias. So it has no affect at all on the `RedirectPermanent` directives.

Comment: I'm trying it but it doesn't seem to work. I get a 404. Any idea why ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Jeremie does `/page1.html` actually exist? If not, then the server will return a 404.

Comment: Actually, it's not really a page1.html, but a wordpress article with a URL like /the-article-long-slug. And yes, the article does exist. But nothing change in the address bar, and I get a 404.

Comment: @Jeremie you need to make sure those rules are **above** all your wordpress rules.

Comment: Great ! This works ! Thanks a lot ! Two more (tiny questions) : (1) I still have ?t=123 at the end of the URL, is this normal ? Can we delete it ? (2) For SEO purposes, what about doing redirections like this ? Is it OK or "bad" ? Thank you so much for all your help !

Comment: @Jeremie I edited the answer, you need a `?` at the end of the rule's target.

Comment: Perfect ! You're very kind to help. Do you know about SEO ? What infuence would it have to do this ?