# .htaccess redirect according to PHP parameters and general case

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

On this other topic : [.htaccess redirect according to PHP parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31679492/htaccess-redirect-according-to-php-parameters) I got help to make redirections according to some PHP parameters, for instance, like

```
/forum/viewtopic.php?t=123 redirected to /page1.html
/forum/viewtopic.php?t=345 redirected to /page7.html
/forum/viewtopic.php?t=89 redirected to page3.html
```

The (working) solution proposed is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^t=123$
RewriteRule ^forum/viewtopic\.php$ /page1.html? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^t=345$
RewriteRule ^forum/viewtopic\.php$ /page7.html? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^t=89$
RewriteRule ^forum/viewtopic\.php$ /page3.html? [L,R=301]
```

I would like to add a "general" case at the end: if no URL matched, and the folder "/forum" is asked, redirect to the root. For instance

```
/forum redirected to /
/forum/viewtopic.php?t=34598237 redirected to /
/forum/something redirected to /
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this line at he end:

```
RewriteRule ^forum / [L,R=301]
```

Since all of your previous conditions had [L] modifier (which instructs any further rules processing), this last condition would only kick in only if any of the previous ones does not match.

Comment: This rule seems to redirect everything like /forum/something (a subfolder, a file...). Is it possible to redirect only mysite.com/forum/, and nothing else (for instance, NOT redirect /forum/page1.php, /forum/folder)

Comment: Solved by myself : `RewriteRule ^forum/$ / [L,R=301]`